# ¿Cómo estructurar un contenido según esta imagen?

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo este auto reto y quisiera saber qué creen en esta comunidad sobre cuál sería mejor estructurar o maquetar el HTML y CSS para un diseño como el de la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo en cuenta, además, las siguientes condiciones:

- Código HTML con el menor número de elementos o anidaciones.
- Usando técnicas CSS modernas y sin tantas líneas de código.
- No usar JavaScript como reto.

Estuve tratando de lograrlo usando `grid`, pero aún no tengo tan claro cómo funciona y no sé cómo centrar el contenido al centro en pantallas superiores a los 1080px. Otra cosa, cuando decida seguir agregando más bloques a la columna 1 se sitúa en la misma fila que el elemento C y no entiendo por qué, además que no se si haya alguna forma de alterar el orden de los elementos para lograr la el diseño "SM":

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background: #f1f2f2;
}

.principal_container{
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.section{
  border: 5px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content_01,
.content_03{
  max-width: 960px;
}

@media (min-width: 720px){

  .principal_container{
    grid-template-columns: 
      [col1-start] calc(100% - 10em - 10px)  
      [col2-end] 10em;
    grid-template-rows: 
      [row1-start] auto 
      [row2-start] auto 
      [row2-end];
  }

  .content_01 {
    grid-column: col1-start;
    grid-row: row1-start ;
  }
  .content_02 {
    grid-column: col2-end ;
    grid-row: row1-start / row2-end;
  }
  .content_03 {
    grid-column: col1-start;
    grid-row: row2-start ;
  }

}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="principal_container">
    
    <section class="section content_01">
      A
    </section>
    <section class="section content_02">
      B
    </section>
    <section class="section content_03">
      C
    </section>   
    
  </div>

</body>
```

Por lo que después opte por `flex` y usar `calc` para lograr mi objetivo. Lo consideré un poco más fácil de usar, pero no sé cómo hacer para que el bloque B se estire hasta la base del contenedor, sin embargo si decido colocar más elementos a la columna 1, si puedo hacerlo sin producir errores. Ejemplo:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background: #f1f2f2;
  font-family: arial;
}

.principal_container{
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: left;
}

.section{
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  order: 2;
}

.content_02{
  order: 3;
}



@media (min-width: 720px){
  .content_01, .content_03{
    width: calc(100% - 10em - 20px);
    max-width: 960px;
  }

  .content_02{
    width: 10em;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="principal_container">
    
    <section class="section content_01">
      A
    </section>
    <section class="section content_02">
      B
    </section>
    <section class="section content_03">
      C
    </section>
    
  </div>

</body>
```

Pero, pienso que no es la solución más óptima, ya que creo que `grid` podría ser la mejor opción, lo único es que no se como solucionar el inconveniente de agregar más elementos posteriores a la columna 1 o alinear al centro en pantallas "XL".

Otra solución que se me ocurrio, es usar `position: absolute` y jugar con el padding del `principal_container`, pero quisiera lograrlo sin alterar el flujo de los elementos.

**¿Como lo solucionarían ustedes?**

Comment: Yo veo dos columnas, una formada por A+C y otra con B. Lo que haría sería crear, por tanto, dos elementos y en el primero meter A y C. El resto es relativamente sencillo: cuando la pantalla se estreche demasiado las dos columnas ocupan todo el ancho, pasando a ser una.

Answer (score 1):

Alinear al centro en pantallas XL es simple (y todas en general). Al contenedor principal `principal_container` le debes indicar que es un elemento de bloque (como es un `div` es automático, así que simplemente le quito el `inline-block`), poner un ancho máximo y luego indicar que los márgenes sean `auto`. El navegador centrará automáticamente el contenedor.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando (las secciones las veremos abajo):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f1f2f2;
  font-family: arial;
}

.principal_container {
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<div class="principal_container">

  <section class="section content_01">
    A
  </section>
  <section class="section content_02">
    B
  </section>
  <section class="section content_03">
    C
  </section>

</div>
```

En tu caso, el ancho máximo no sería 1024px, sino 960px (el máximo de A/C) + 10em de B + 20px de los márgenes de las secciones. De ese modo estarías imponiendo un ancho máximo efectivo de 960px a A y C, sin especificarlo de manera explicita.

Ahora, para lo que quieres de maquetar las secciones, puedes usar un `grid`. Y para ser sincero: lo tenías básicamente hecho, lo único que he cambiado con respecto a tu ejemplo ha sido un valor y ya funciona. Quita el `calc` del ancho de la columna en `grid-template-columns` y dale el valor `auto` para que A y C siempre ocupen el espacio disponible.

Puedes dejar el `order: 3` para el bloque B, porque se seguirá aplicando con `grid` también. Y si no especificas columnas, entonces automáticamente ocuparán todo el ancho (al ser secciones) y harás que B aparezca al final sin afectar a su posicionamiento cuando la pantalla sea más grande de 720px.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f1f2f2;
  font-family: arial;
}

.principal_container {
  display: grid;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto auto;
  max-width: calc(960px + 10em + 20px);
}

.section {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.content_02 {
  order: 3;
}

@media all and (min-width: 720px) {
  .principal_container {
    grid-template-columns: [col1-start] auto [col2-end] 10em;
    grid-template-rows: [row1-start] auto [row2-start] auto [row2-end];
  }
  .content_01 {
    grid-column: col1-start;
    grid-row: row1-start;
  }
  .content_02 {
    grid-column: col2-end;
    grid-row: row1-start / row2-end;
  }
  .content_03 {
    grid-column: col1-start;
    grid-row: row2-start;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="principal_container">

  <section class="section content_01">
    A
  </section>
  <section class="section content_02">
    B
  </section>
  <section class="section content_03">
    C
  </section>

</div>
```

---

Sobre añadir nuevos elementos: si añades nuevos bloques a tu estructura, estos elementos van a afectar el tamaño y la estructura del `grid` y tendrías que cambiar el CSS porque ahora mismo es específico para 3 elementos.

Lo que podrías hacer sería especificar que va a haber dos columnas (1 auto y la otra de 10em) y que todas las filas van a ser `auto`. Para todas las secciones, la columna será la 1, y no hace falta especificar un row, que será `auto` por defecto. Luego para `.content_02` especificar que su columna va a ser la 2 y para la fila lo que puedes hacer es especificar que va a empezar en la primera y terminar en un número muy grande (más grande que el número de nuevos elementos que se vayan a añadir), de ese modo crecerá automáticamente hasta ocupar todo el espacio disponible (tiene que haber un modo mejor de hacerlo, esto es demasiado *hacky*).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f1f2f2;
  font-family: arial;
}

.principal_container {
  display: grid;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto auto;
  max-width: calc(960px + 10em + 20px);
}

.section {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.content_02 {
  order: 3;
}

@media all and (min-width: 720px) {
  .principal_container {
    grid-template-columns: auto 10em;
  }
  section {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  .content_02 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 999999;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="principal_container">

  <section class="section content_01">
    A
  </section>
  <section class="section content_02">
    B
  </section>
  <section class="section content_03">
    C
  </section>
  <section class="section content_04">
    D
  </section>
  <section class="section content_05">
    E
  </section>
</div>
```